# Is it is possible to increase size of pictureBox or Highlight in On mouseover event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

![enter image description here][1]I am new to C#. Please help me. I wants to highlight or increase size of a PictureBox
when mouse move over it.

I use PictureBoxes instead of Buttons

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx

Comment: We pretty much require one to show us their effort. In other words - where is the code you wrote? What's wrong with it? What isn't working with it? If you don't have any code, why not?

Comment: I have a complete program using PictureBox as Main menu I dont have any code of Mouse event yet.  Oded♦

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MouseEnter` event:

```
public void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

In the `MouseLeave` event:

```
public void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
}
```

This highlights the `pictureBox1` in blue when mouse is over it and changes it to normal color when mouse leaves it's area.

Hope this helps.